# JetbrainのPycharmの拡張機能を使ってJuliaを動かすとエラーがでる

Tags: julia

Pycharmの拡張機能でJuliaを動かしています。
プログラムを実行すると、以下のメッセージが表示されます。
どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

```
IDE エラーが発生しました
詳細を確認してレポートを送信してください
```

Comment: Juliaをインストールし、JuliaのパスをPycharmに設定していますか？

Comment: Juliaはインストールしています。「JuliaのパスをPycharmに設定」とは環境変数を使うということでしょうか？　もしそうならそれらの設定法をまとめた記事をご存じありませんか？

Answer (score 0):

こちらの環境のPyCharm 2021.3.1 (Community Edition)で、Juliaのプラグインを有効にすると以下のエラーが発生しました。質問された方のエラーと同じ内容です。

```
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: The default implementation of method 'getId' is deprecated, you need to override it in 'class org.ice1000.julia.lang.execution.JuliaRunConfigurationFactory'. The default implementation delegates to 'getName' which may be localized, but return value of this method must not depend on current localization. [Plugin: org.ice1000.julia]
```

この問題は既に報告されています。まだ解決していないようです。

https://github.com/JuliaEditorSupport/julia-intellij/issues/671

```
IDE error after Julia plugin installation #671
 Open
ML-Data-Science-cloud opened this issue 10 hours ago · 0 comments
Comments
@ML-Data-Science-cloud
 
ML-Data-Science-cloud commented 10 hours ago
Hi @ice1000
I have a PyCharm Version: 2021.3.1 installed and once I've installed Julia plugin it gives me an error:

IDE error occurred:
```

PyCharm 2021.2.2 (Community Edition)ではこのエラーは発生しませんでした。

このエラーが発生することにおり、どんな影響があるのかはわかっていませんが、PyCharmのバージョンを2021.2.2に落とせばよい問題とは思えません。
私はJuliaのプラグインが対応するを待つしかないと考えています。

【PyCharmでのJuliaの設定】は必要なのですが、この問題とは無関係のようです。

---

【PyCharmでのJuliaの設定】

もしPycharmでJuliaのパスを設定していないのであれば設定が必要です。

設定の方法は以下のとおりです。

- PyCharmを起動し、メニューの[ファイル]-[設定]で設定画面を表示し、「言語＆フレームワーク」の「Julia」を選択します。
- ウィンドウ右側のJulia executableにJuliaのパスを指定します。

Comment: 設定しました。プログラムは動くのですが「IDE エラーが発生しました　詳細を確認してレポートを送信してください」というエラーが出ます。

Comment: プログラムは正常に動作するのですね。「IDE エラーが発生しました　詳細を確認してレポートを送信してください」というエラーはどこに出るのでしょうか？

Comment: 画面右下。　"1:1 CRLF UTF-8 4スペース Python 3.8" と表示されているすぐ上です。

Comment: 「IDE エラーが発生しました　詳細を確認してレポートを送信してください」をクリックするとエラーの詳細が表示されると思います。エラーの詳細を質問に追記して欲しいです。

Comment: こちらの環境でも再現できました。PyCharmを2021.3.1にバージョンアップしたら同じと思われるエラーが発生しました。

Comment: エラーの詳細は長すぎるので一部だけ　com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: The default implementation of method 'getId' is deprecated, you need to override it in 'class org.ice1000.julia.lang.execution.JuliaRunConfigurationFactory'. The default implementation delegates to 'getName' which may be localized, but return value of this method must not depend on current localization. [Plugin: org.ice1000.julia]
 at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.createPluginException(PluginManagerCore.java:270)
 at com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginProblemReporterImpl.createPluginExceptionByClass(PluginProblemReporterImp

Comment: 私のPyCharmは2021.3 (Professional Edition)です。